# Can't Install Chrome9 driver on Win XP SP2 Inside VirtualBox

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, vga

I am trying to install Windows XP SP2 and the installation was find. However when installing VIA Chrome9 driver I am hitting an erorr. Below is the error log:
Has anyone has sucess with VirtualBox + Chrome9 + WinXP?
Thanks!
    ********** S3 GRAPHICS SETUP LOG - Started 2010/08/03 1:11:54 AM **********

```
         *****  Please scroll to the end of *****
        ***** this document for the results. *****

S3Iset32 v2.00.57-0525, 2.00.55.0525 (IShield 10.50.0.125)
  System: Win XP SP2  Build 2600 (Service Pack 2)
  Signature: 18-9968 (ANSI)
  Caller cmdline: ''
  SupportDir: 'C:\DOCUME~1\User\LOCALS~1\Temp\{F0D96B55-E583-48E2-8C22-32EE21F0A431}\{5A118437-3B7B-402B-955C-A74B847CB0DE}\'
Mode: Unattended, Normal
    AllowReboot: TRUE
         Prompt: TRUE
   SilentReboot: TRUE
         Prompt: FALSE
   RemoveWinINF: FALSE
   PreInstFiles: FALSE
   No UI Reboot: FALSE
    MenuAnimOff: FALSE
  MenuShadowOff: FALSE
Find VendorID: 5333
  Driver INF at: C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\P4M900_VGA_MB\P4M900\Win2K-XP\dc04i.inf
  Find hardware code: 0
  Custom uninstall info: C:\WINDOWS\UChromeP.uns
    Uninst DLL: C:\PROGRA~1\S3\UChromeP\s3iset32.dll
    Uninst Log: C:\PROGRA~1\S3\UChromeP\UChromeP.uns
    Reg uninst key: C:\PROGRA~1\S3\UChromeP\s3minset.exe /u C:\PROGRA~1\S3\UChromeP\UChromeP.uns
    Add. dir to remove: C:\Program Files\InstallShield Installation Information\{3F7B8FA3-42A8-4B39-8D35-1ACC5F1466BB}
Installing VIA Chrome9 HC IGP Family Display...
-> Setup was unable to complete the installation.  Check the progress log in your Windows directory for more details. (-3)->C:\WINDOWS\s3iscfg.log
** Installation Failed **
!! Setup was aborted !!
******** End of progress log ********
```

Answer (score 2):

VirtualBox is emulating a machine with its own hardware - your virtual machine does not have that graphics chip - it has a Virtualbox one.

To get decent graohics you *do* need to install a driver as part of the `Guest Additions`.

Start the machine and select `Install guest additions` from the `Devices` menu.